# What problems would using the reserved keywords DATE and TIME as column names cause in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, naming-convention, reserved-word

`DATE` is an SQL Reserved Word and `TIME` is a PL/SQL Reserved Word in Oracle (listed in `SQL> HELP RESERVED WORDS`). What problems would using them as column names cause in Oracle?

The database server runs:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it won't let you.

Oracle is stricter than other RDBMSes and you'll get an `ORA-00904: invalid identifier` if you try a `CREATE TABLE` with a reserved word.

However, you can force it to do so by surrounding the name in quotes, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
  "date" date
);
```

... But in doing so, you're essentially admitting you're doing something wrong (plus it makes the name case-sensitive).

Best practice would be to avoid case-sensitive object names, and avoid using reserved words.

Documentation link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621), with a list of reserved words, which backs up what I've stated:

> You cannot use Oracle SQL reserved words as nonquoted identifiers.
>   Quoted identifiers can be reserved words, although this is not
>   recommended

In summary: Just don't.